# ASP web application timeout and possible configuration issues

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, iis, timeout

I have an asp/IIS application deployed on our server that runs fine every time we reboot it or restart due to new application modifications. However, after 10-20 minutes it starts to chug and timeout even when trying to repeat the exact same steps as I've done before when the application was running fine.

The web application is used to pull data from queries. It ran fine when the database it was pulling from was close to us, but we recently had to change hosts and now our database is halfway around the world. So I am not sure if this is an issue that is focused on the configuration end or if we have to do something within the application code itself to prevent the timeout.

The application is querying a Postgres database if this information is of any use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of IIS is it running on? edit... this may not matter after reading only the db was moved.

Comment: We're using IIS version 7. Sorry that I did not include that in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link first.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/technoNet/SessionTimeout02192009052301AM/SessionTimeout.aspx

Otherwise

I think it's due to Forms Authentication timeout settings.

"The forms authentication ticket can time out in two ways. The first scenario occurs if you use absolute expiration. With absolute expiration, the authentication ticket expires when the expiration time expires. For example, you set an expiration of 20 minutes, and a user visits the site at 2:00 PM. The user will be redirected to the login page if the user visits the site after 2:20 PM.

If you use sliding expiration, the scenario is a bit more complicated. The cookie and the resulting ticket are updated if the user visits the site after the expiration time is half-expired. For example, you set an expiration of 20 minutes by using sliding expiration. A user visits the site at 2:00 PM, and the user receives a cookie that is set to expire at 2:20 PM. The expiration is only updated if the user visits the site after 2:10 PM. If the user visits the site at 2:09 PM, the ticket is not updated because half of the expiration time has not passed. If the user then waits 12 minutes, visiting the site at 2:21 PM, the ticket will be expired. The user is redirected to the login page."

Also please go through below link you can get more idea on this.

http://itworksonmymachine.wordpress.com/2008/07/17/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout/ 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910439 
http://www.abstraction.net/ViewArticle.aspx?articleID=74 
http://codeasp.net/blogs/vivek_iit/microsoft-net/848/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-state-timeout

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem with an endless loop in the Session_End event. If your session timeout is 20min that could cause the problem as everything runs ok before. Maybe you try to log something in Session_End which causes trouble with the database?

Comment: The timeout isn't 20 minutes. It's just that if the application has been deployed and active on the server for over 20 minutes we've noticed that anyone connecting to it starts to see timeout issues. Sorry that I didn't clarify this

Comment: @Seb: That's what I mean. Per default the Session timeout in asp.net is 20 minutes. Therefore if you get strange behavior after 20 minutes it could be that a session ends and causes this trouble. At least that was the problem we had in our application. Another possibility is that a firewall closes a port which is used by your database connection, but I'm not a network specialist.